# Which Url I need to use with one note endpoint to read shared notebooks

Tags: sharepoint, office365, onenote

I am trying to access shared notebooks in my organization using onenote endpoint.
https://www.onenote.com/api/beta/myorganization/siteCollections/FromUrl(url='{full-path-to-SharePoint-site}’)

I have used the full URI of the one note page that I want to read, as full-path-to-SharePoint-site. But I am getting this error.

{
  "error":{
    "code":"20158","message":"Unable to get SiteMetadta for the url specified in the request.","@api.url":"http://aka.ms/onenote-errors#C20158"
  }
}

Looks like I am not using the full-path-to-SharePoint-site properly. Any suggestions what URI it refers to ?

Answer (score 0):

using PPE environment URL against Prod OneNote endpoint, which won't work.
You will need to provide prod tenant URL to OneNote endpoint.